# binding ComboBox to DataGrid in the code

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

Hi I am trying to dynamically bind ComboBox in the DataGrid inside the code. I saw a few answers related to this but none of them were helpful. The general opinion is to use the DataTempleteColumn but that also gives no result. Here is my code

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Name="ButFill" Content="Fill Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="373,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DaGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134" Margin="25,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="289" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="text" Binding="{Binding Path=col1}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="combobox" Width="105" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fill_items}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="template combo" Width="105">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="TempCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fill_items}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind is

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Class MainWindow
    Public Property Table As New ObservableCollection(Of Test.dataset)()
    Public Property fill_items As New ObservableCollection(Of String)
    Private Sub ButFill_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ButFill.Click
        Dim temp As New Test.dataset()
        Dim cb As New ComboBox
        fill_items.Add("ItemNo1")
        fill_items.Add("ItemNo2")
        cb.ItemsSource = fill_items
        temp.col1 = " Hello"
        temp.col2 = cb
        temp.col3 = cb
        Table.Add(temp)
        DaGrid.DataContext = Table
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class dataset
    Public Property col1 As String
    Public Property col2 As ComboBox
    Public Property col3 As ComboBox
End Class
```

The problem I see are:

1) The DataGridComboBox Column dosen't show the it until entered in the edit mode.
2) Both the Combobox are empty, but the Collections "Table" seems to have a combobox.count of 2.

Am I doing anything wrong?
Could somebody show me a proper complete example of binding ComboBox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill_items` needs to be a public property in your `dataset` class, because bindings in

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Name="TempCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fill_items}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

refer to each item of your bound collection. In your case it's a `dataset` item.

You can't just simply use RelativeSource or ElementName to find the DataGrid and bind to that, because `DataGridColumn`s won't be added to the visual tree, hence those bindings can't work.

Comment: @FlorianGI, yes this way works but the thing is after the user makes a selctection in the combobox I need to read it back in the code. I cannot read the selected item as it is done normally in the combobox or from datagrid column. In what way can I read back the selction?

Comment: Create a property in `dataset` which should hold this value and bind it to the COMBOBOX' SelectedItem property (Mode=TwoWay).

Comment: @FlorianGI, is it this way `<ComboBox Name="TempCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fill_items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=items,Mode=TwoWay}"/>`  and a property in dataset as `Public Property item As String` ?   if it is like this then it is not getting binded for me

Comment: Binding path is `items` (with an s at the end), but your property is called `item`. Just to be sure: add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to this binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show fill_items in combobox which is in the DataContext of the Window, then you will need to update your comboboxcolumn binding to use the `BindingProxy` because DataGrid columns are not in the Visualtree of the datagrid.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyBindingProxy x:Key="myproxy" BindingData="{Binding}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and you have to set the DataContext of the Mainwindow to itself like `DataContext =this;` in constructor

then you need to write the class for MyBindingProxy like:

```
public class MyBindingProxy : Freezable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BindingData", typeof(object), 
        typeof(MyBindingProxy ), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new MyBindingProxy();
    }

    public object BindingData
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(BindingDataProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(BindingDataProperty , value); }
    }

}
```

Then you can update binding as:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="combobox" Width="105" ItemsSource="{Binding BindingData.fill_items, Source={StaticResource myproxy}}"/>
```

Comment: Still dosent work it gives me an error when running in Debug mode. `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=fill_items; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=58943162); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`